# what does the "event.type " in the book mean?

Tags: javascript, web

I read the  javascript for  web developer and I find  that words

```html
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(event.type)">
```

I don't understand why the books say it output "click" ;why the event.type point to that

Comment: Because `event.type` contains the type of event, and type of the Click-event is `click`...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type…?

Comment: The property just tells you the type of the event. This is not very usefull in a click-only handler, but sometimes you handle different events with the same function (ex. mousedown / touchstart), and then you need to know which type of event is at hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alerts the "event.type". The event type is "click" as in this alert only works when you "click" the button. See more examples here: https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events

Answer (score 0):

The `type` property of an `event` object tells you the type of event it is.

It is a *click* event because it the event listener is a click event listener (assigned with the `onclick` attribute).

It might be more useful if you were using an event handler function that was shared among different types of events and you needed subtle differences between how they were handled.